# How to extract attached credentials from a url?

Tags: python, python-requests

In a URL like this: 
`'https://usertest:userpass@localhost:8080/mypath'`. How do I extract the information such as username and password in python? For eg. the information I want to extract from the above URL would be `usertest` and `userpass`. I could extract these attached web credentials such as username and password using regex, but that seems to be a bit complicated and I am hoping if there is already a built-in solution for this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'https://usertest:userpass@localhost:8080/mypath'
parsed = urlparse(url)
print(parsed.username)
print(parsed.password)
```

Check [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing)